# How to generate HMAC-SHA1 signature for oAuth

Tags: ios, swift, oauth, hmac, hmacsha1

I'm using the code below for generating `HMAC-SHA1` signature, but I get this error during authentication request:

> "oauth_signature does not match expected value"

Can anyone tell me how to generate correct signature? I also checked [oAuthSwift](https://github.com/OAuthSwift/OAuthSwift) library `allHTTPHeaderFields` for Tumblr and it works on this code.

```
Tumblr_oAuth-Bridging-Header.h
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonHMAC.h>
```

And

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let consumerKey = "SpFweFQePdB1I6GnbX2TKCrnD8sObObExERLtw1RBcaEZPFV26"
    let consumerSecret = "HCLK7WnNuZM7ohCoSqNixNhCs2YmASfnL8tkYaQvuh9DEj05o3"
    let requestTokenUrl = "www.tumblr.com/oauth/request_token"
    let authorizeUrl = "https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/authorize"
    let accessTokenUrl = "https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/access_token"
    let oauthTokenSecret = ""

    @IBAction func login(_ sender: Any) {

        let oauth_timestamp = String(Int64(Date().timeIntervalSince1970))
        let oauth_nonce = generateNonce()//: CFString = CFUUIDCreateString(nil, uuid)

        let parameters =  ["oauth_timestamp": "\(oauth_timestamp)", "oauth_callback": "oauth-swift://oauth-callback/tumblr", "oauth_signature_method": "HMAC-SHA1", "oauth_version": "1.0", "oauth_consumer_key": "SpFweFQePdB1I6GnbX2TKCrnD8sObObExERLtw1RBcaEZPFV26", "oauth_nonce": "\(oauth_nonce)"]

        let url = URL(string:"https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/request_token")
        let method = "POST"

        let encodedTokenSecret = self.oauthTokenSecret.urlEncoded
        let encodedConsumerSecret = self.consumerSecret.urlEncoded

        let signingKey = "\(encodedConsumerSecret)&\(encodedTokenSecret)"
        print(parameters)
        var parameterComponents = parameters.urlEncodedQuery.components(separatedBy: "&")
        parameterComponents.sort {
            let p0 = $0.components(separatedBy: "=")
            let p1 = $1.components(separatedBy: "=")
            if p0.first == p1.first { return p0.last ?? "" < p1.last ?? "" }
            return p0.first ?? "" < p1.first ?? ""
        }

        let parameterString = parameterComponents.joined(separator: "&")
        let encodedParameterString = parameterString.urlEncoded
        let encodedURL = url?.absoluteString.urlEncoded

        let signatureBaseString = "\(method)&\(String(describing: encodedURL))&\(encodedParameterString)"

        let key = signingKey//.data(using: .utf8)!
        let msg = signatureBaseString//.data(using: .utf8)!

        let signature : String = msg.hmac(algorithm: HMACAlgorithm.SHA1, key: key)
        print("signature",signature)

        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/request_token")!)

        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = ["Authorization": "OAuth oauth_callback=\"oauth-swift%3A%2F%2Foauth-callback%2Ftumblr\", oauth_consumer_key=\"SpFweFQePdB1I6GnbX2TKCrnD8sObObExERLtw1RBcaEZPFV26\", oauth_nonce=\"\(oauth_nonce)\", oauth_signature=\"\(signature.urlEncoded)\", oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\", oauth_timestamp=\"\(oauth_timestamp)\", oauth_version=\"1.0\""]

        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
                print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
                return
            }

            if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(String(describing: response))")
            }

            let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            print("responseString = \(String(describing: responseString))")
        }
        task.resume()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
}
public func generateNonce() -> String {
    let uuidString = UUID().uuidString
    return uuidString.substring(to: 8)
}
enum HMACAlgorithm {
    case MD5, SHA1, SHA224, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512

    func toCCHmacAlgorithm() -> CCHmacAlgorithm {
        var result: Int = 0
        switch self {
        case .MD5:
            result = kCCHmacAlgMD5
        case .SHA1:
            result = kCCHmacAlgSHA1
        case .SHA224:
            result = kCCHmacAlgSHA224
        case .SHA256:
            result = kCCHmacAlgSHA256
        case .SHA384:
            result = kCCHmacAlgSHA384
        case .SHA512:
            result = kCCHmacAlgSHA512
        }
        return CCHmacAlgorithm(result)
    }

    func digestLength() -> Int {
        var result: CInt = 0
        switch self {
        case .MD5:
            result = CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH
        case .SHA1:
            result = CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH
        case .SHA224:
            result = CC_SHA224_DIGEST_LENGTH
        case .SHA256:
            result = CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH
        case .SHA384:
            result = CC_SHA384_DIGEST_LENGTH
        case .SHA512:
            result = CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH
        }
        return Int(result)
    }
}
extension String {
    func hmac(algorithm: HMACAlgorithm, key: String) -> String {
        let cKey = key.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        let cData = self.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        var result = [CUnsignedChar](repeating: 0, count: Int(algorithm.digestLength()))
        CCHmac(algorithm.toCCHmacAlgorithm(), cKey!, strlen(cKey!), cData!, strlen(cData!), &result)
        let hmacData:NSData = NSData(bytes: result, length: (Int(algorithm.digestLength())))
        let hmacBase64 = hmacData.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions.lineLength76Characters)// Encoding76CharacterLineLength)
        return String(hmacBase64)
    }

    var urlEncoded: String {
        let customAllowedSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._~")
        return self.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: customAllowedSet)!
    }

    var urlQueryEncoded: String? {
        return self.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)
    }

    func substring(to offset: String.IndexDistance) -> String {
        let to = self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: offset)
        return String(self[..<to])
    }
}
extension Dictionary {

    var urlEncodedQuery: String {
        var parts = [String]()

        for (key, value) in self {
            let keyString = "\(key)".urlEncoded
            let valueString = "\(value)".urlEncoded
            let query = "\(keyString)=\(valueString)"
            parts.append(query)
        }

        return parts.joined(separator: "&")
    }

}
```

Comment: Replace your secret key data/auth details with dummy data. if these are actually your API access tokens then I would regenerate them

Comment: @Scriptable Can you please explain? how

Comment: I mean in the code above it looks like you are giving your credentials away online for everyone to see. replace them with dummy data. just replace the text with X's or something. just dont give your personal access details away online

Comment: @Scriptable  i know but its my test app key’s ;)

Comment: ok, just checking ;o)